# Making a button to link to a create method for a different controller

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a week entity and a day entity which are tables and controllers for each. As it stands in my application, you have to create the week then the days separately. In the weeks tab, if you click on "Details" for a week, you can see the days and the data in them in a table.

My question is, how do you create a button that would bring you to the `DayController` create page so that I can make the days from the week tab.

Here is the HTML for the Week Details, I am new to this and I figure this is the code that would help you understand:

```
@model Utilities.Models.Week

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Week</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WeekID)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.WeekID)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WeekNo)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.WeekNo)
        </dd>


        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Days)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        WeekID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        DayNo
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Day of the Week
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Data 1
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        More data
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                @foreach (var item in Model.Days)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Week.WeekID)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DayNo)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DayofWeek)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data1)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.More Data)
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                }

            </table>
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>

/*
| My attempt at going to the create day page below but it doesn't work. Am I referencing it wrong?
| Basically, I want to click "Create Day" and go to the create page for Day.
*/
    @Html.ActionLink("Create Day", "Create", new { id = Model.Days.DayID}) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.WeekID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

I can include any other code that might be needed to help answer.
`Days` is the navigation property in the Week model.

When I run the code above, I get:

`CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Utilities.Models.Day>' does not contain a definition for 'DayID' and no extension method 'DayID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Utilities.Models.Day>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

but Day does have a DayID.

Answer (score 0):

With that error I suppose your `Model.Days` is a collection of `Day` objects, so that can find a property named `DayID`. To do what you wand you need to specify the index of the object you want in that collection. Try to do `Model.Days[0].DayID` for example and tell me if that works, please.

Code:

```
@model Utilities.Models.Week

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Week</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WeekID)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.WeekID)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WeekNo)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.WeekNo)
        </dd>


        <dt>
            @{
                var count = 0;
                foreach(var day in Model.Days)
                {
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => day.DayofWeek)
                    if(count!= Model.Days - 1)
                    { @(", ") }
                    count++;
                }
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        WeekID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        DayNo
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Day of the Week
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Data 1
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        More data
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                @foreach (var item in Model.Days)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Week.WeekID)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DayNo)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DayofWeek)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data1)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MoreData)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Create Day", "Create", new { id = item.DayID})
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </table>
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.WeekID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

UPDATE:

If you want to create a new day just change you code with this:

```
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create Day", "Create", "Day")
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.WeekID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
```

Comment: It is a collection of days, yes. It did not work, I got: `CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Utilities.Models.Day>'
`. I do not want one that is already there though, I want to create a new day.

Comment: Ok. But now I have a question: if you want to create a new day why you are passing a `DayID` to the `Create` controller action by the `id` parameter?

Comment: I did it along the lines of the one for edit but realise now how very very wrong that was. Sorry about that. Do you know if there is any way I can put a button beside edit that brings me to the create page for a day?

Comment: check my updated answer please. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: No that creates a new week. My above code is the code for the details page in the week controller. I'm trying to find a way to go from there to the create page in the day controller.

Comment: Ok, so you need to specify the controller where you create a new day day, like this: `@Html.ActionLink("Create Day", "Create", "Day")`

Comment: That didn't work at first but I changed `DayController` to `Day` and it worked. Thank you very much! :D Much appreciated!